# Error when user is not signed in : function nil.id/0 is undefined

Tags: phoenix-framework

I want to hide edit and delete buttons from users that didnt created topic.
I connected user_id with topics table and that works good.
When user make a new topic his id is in topic user_id.
But now when user is not logged in %{user: nil} i get an error:

```
function nil.id/0 is undefined
```

require_auth.ex

```
def call(conn , _params) do
  if conn.assigns[:user] do
    conn
  else
    conn
    |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in.")
    |> redirect(to: ZivotWeb.Router.Helpers.topic_path(conn, :index))
    |> halt()
  end
```

set_user.ex

```
def call(conn, _params) do
  user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id)

  cond do
    user = user_id && Repo.get(User, user_id) ->
        assign(conn, :user, user)
    true ->
        assign(conn, :user, nil)
  end
end
```

I dont know if u need it but there is auth_controller.ex

```
def callback(%{assigns: %{ueberauth_auth: auth}} = conn ,params) do

    user_params = %{token: auth.credentials.token, email: auth.info.email, provider: "github"}
   changeset = Zivot.User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
   signin(conn,changeset)

  end

  def signout(conn,_params) do
    conn
    |> configure_session(drop: true)
    |> put_flash(:info, "you successfully Signed Out!")
    |> redirect(to: Routes.topic_path(conn, :index))

  end
 defp signin(conn, changeset) do
   case insert_or_update_user(changeset) do
     {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Welcome back!")
      |> put_session(:user_id, user.id)
      |> redirect(to: Routes.topic_path(conn, :index))
    {:error, _reason} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "Error signing in")
      |> redirect(to: Routes.topic_path(conn, :index))

   end
 end

 defp insert_or_update_user(changeset) do
   case Repo.get_by(User, email: changeset.changes.email) do
     nil ->
       Repo.insert(changeset)
     user -> {:ok, user}
   end
 end
```

Comment: I forgot to add index.html when i try to hide buttons:
     `<%= if @conn.assigns.user.id == topic.user_id do %>
     <div class="right"> <button> <button> <% end %>`

Comment: its fixed by putting 
`<%= if @conn.assigns.user && @conn.assigns.user.id == topic.user_id do %>`

Comment: you should submit this as answer